# First Order Logic representation of program

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I have numerous records, composed of words.
Each word gets translated into vectors, with a variable number of channels, **provided** that that word exists in a specific lookup dictionary.

For n number of words in every record, based upon c number of channels that each vector-based representation of the words possesses, a function f is fed this stream of data and outputs a probability p.

n and c are both constants.

How might this be represented using first-order-logic?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by expressing this situation in first-order logic? Most mathematicians would describe the situation in words, as you have done.

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is the "done thing" in academic papers. A written explanation like this would be considered informal, and somewhat less professional in my discipline.

Comment: What discipline is that?

Comment: @RobArthan Computer science

Comment: Interesting. The bulk of the CS literature tends to be even more informal about its presentation of mathematics than mathematicians are, although some communities e.g., the POPL world, have begun to demand more formality. Also there are many proponents of rigorous, so-called [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) in computer applications. You will probably get a better answer if you ask in a CS forum.

Comment: I have few questions : Could you clarify "based upon c number of channels"? Is the stream of data composed of one or an arbitrary number of records, or is the stream the content of only one record? And is the probability p, just a number in [0,1] or a real discrete probabilistic law in which case, what is its domain?

Comment: @PaulCottalorda sorry for the delay in replying. The stream is like an r*c size matrix, with r being the number of records, and c being the number of channels. 

The probability is ultimately a truth value, so can be represented as either 0 or 1.